# Null Propagation - Execute function upon null check

Tags: c#, null-propagation-operator

Can this be implemented using Null propagation operator (??) ?

```
origObj = model.ProjectId != null ? GetObj(model.ProjectId.Value) : null;
```

Comment: You need to let `GetObj` decide on what to do with `null` inputs, otherwise you will need to make that check everywhere when you call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, null propagation wont help you here, because it is working in the opposite direction from what you want.

It will check if first part is null and only in that case run the second part. I cant imagine how you will invert it.

But as @JohanP said it is much better to move that check into your function:

```
public object GetObj(object input)
{
   if (input == null) return null;
   ....
}

origObj = GetObj(model.ProjectId);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be implemented using Null propagation operator (??) ?

```
var origObj = model.ProjectId != null ? GetObj(model.ProjectId.Value) : null;
```

First of all the operator `??` is the *Null Coalescing* operator. If you want to use that, it simply means if left side of `??` is null, then do right side else do left side. So in your case it will not work because if you were to write this:

```
var origObj = model.ProjectId ?? GetObj(model.ProjectId.Value);
```

it will mean: if `model.ProjectId` is not null, assign it to `origObj`. Otherwise, assign the return value from `GetObj(model.ProjectId.Value)` and it will crash because `model.ProjectId` is null.

The *Null Propagation* operator `?` works like this: If left side of `?` is not null then call something on it. For example:

```
public class Foo
{ 
    public void Bar() {}
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo?.Bar();
```

In your situation the ternary operator will do fine. But it all depends on the return type of `GetObj` method. If the method is returning `void` then it will not compile. If the method is returning a primitive type, then you will need to cast like this because both branches of the ternary operator must return the same type. For example, if `GetObj` is returning a `bool`, then you would need this:

```
 var origObj = model.ProjectId != null 
     ? GetObj(model.ProjectId.Value) : 
     (bool?)null;
```

**Gotcha**

Finally, if you leave the null check to the `GetObj` method you may end up in trouble and your program may crash if the `GetObj` method is like this:

```
public object GetObj(object value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot call with null");
    }
}
```